# Does the MSAL libary support response_mode of form_post

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL library (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to auth to Azure B2C.

When MSAL does the authorize request, it sets the response_mode to fragment. With the fragment mode the authorization code is returned as a query parameter or fragment of the URL But a recent change in Azure AD, has resulted in very long URL responses which can be blocked by firewalls.

Microsoft now recommend using a response_mode of form_post.

Can the MSAL library be configured to use a response_mode of form_post?

Answer (score 0):

The response_mode appears to always default to fragment.

See
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/2343
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2228